# How to duplicate a single bit to a UInt in Chisel 3?

Tags: verilog, bit, chisel

I'm looking for a Chisel way to do the following job:

```
wire [3:0] word;
wire bit;

assign word = {4{bit}};
```

I'm currently doing it like this:

```scala
val word = Wire(UInt(4.W))
val bit = Wire(Bool())

word := Cat(bit, bit, bit, bit)
```

However, this solution isn't very tidy when I need a bigger number:

```scala
val bigWord = Wire(UInt(32.W))

bigWord := Cat(bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit, bit)
io.out := summon_cthulhu()
```

Is there a better way to do this? Like Verilog `assign bigWord = {32{bit}}`?

Comment: Based on [this](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/doc/chisel-cheatsheet3.pdf) you can use `Fill()` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Qiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572285/qiu)'s comment is right. Using [`chisel3.util.Fill`](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/util/Fill$.html) is the right way to go.

To concretize this, the following Chisel:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental.MultiIOModule
import chisel3.util.Fill

class FooModule(n: Int = 32) extends MultiIOModule {
  val a: UInt = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val b: UInt = IO(Output(UInt(n.W)))
  b := Fill(n, a)
}
```

Produces the following Verilog:

```
module FooModule(
  input         clock,
  input         reset,
  input         a,
  output [31:0] b
);
  assign b = a ? 32'hffffffff : 32'h0;
endmodule
```

Note that `Fill` will use a mux in the special case of filling by something with a width of one. Otherwise, this will do explicit concatenations in a tree.

As an aside, if you choose to do the concatenations explicitly, FIRRTL actually has a dedicated transform called `CombineCats` that will try to clean this up for you. In the following, alternative example `n - 1` temporaries are created where each bit is explicitly concatenated:

```scala
class BarModule(n: Int = 32) extends MultiIOModule {
  val a: UInt = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val b: UInt = IO(Output(UInt(n.W)))
  b := Seq.fill(n)(a.asUInt).reduce(_ ## _)
}
```

You'll get the following Verilog:

```
module BarModule(
  input         clock,
  input         reset,
  input         a,
  output [31:0] b
);
  wire [9:0] _T_8;
  wire [18:0] _T_17;
  wire [27:0] _T_26;
  wire [30:0] _T_29;
  assign _T_8 = {a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a};
  assign _T_17 = {_T_8,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a};
  assign _T_26 = {_T_17,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a};
  assign _T_29 = {_T_26,a,a,a};
  assign b = {_T_29,a};
endmodule
```

You will not, however, get the benefits of concatenation in a tree structure. If you were instead to use a `UInt(32.W)` as the input, the latter would be much less efficient.